# cosd and sind with sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

There seems to be no equivalent for `cosd`, `sind` in sympy (ie cosine and sine for arguments in degrees). Is there any simple way to implement those functions ?

For numpy, I did :

```
numpy.cosd = lambda x : numpy.cos( numpy.deg2rad(x) )
```

Something like :

```
sympy.cosd = lambda x : sympy.cos( sympy.pi/180*x )
```

works for evaluation, but the expression is printed as :

```
cos(pi*x/180)
```

which is not great for readability (I have complicated expression due to 3D coordinates changes). Is there any way to create a `sympy.cosd` function which evaluates `cos(pi/180 * x)` but prints `cosd(x)`?

Comment: Many mathematical formulas look beautiful when working in radians, but [sprout `pi/180` warts](https://qedinsight.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/why-radian-measure-makes-life-easier-in-mathematics-and-physics/) when working in degrees. It's better to work in radians and avoid degrees entirely -- or convert to degrees at the end if you absolutely must.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the link. Then how can the replacement be done ? if i have an expression `y=sympy.cos(x)`, `y.subs(sympy.cos, sympy.cosd)` does not work with the above definition of `sympy.cosd` (as it's not a sympy function but just a usual lambda function). `y.subs(x, pi/180*x)` works here, but if the expression in the cos is complicated (like polynomial expression of various parameters) it might not be convenient to search which parameters must be replace with a `pi/180` and which must not.

Comment: Let `x`, `theta`, `phi`, etc. be Symbols representing quantities in radians. Keep a list of these symbols: `angles = [x, theta, phi]`. Then, at the very end, use `y.subs([(angle, angle*pi/180) for angle in angles])` to change the meaning of the symbols to degrees.

Answer (score 1):

`sympy` does have a [radian converter](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/functions/trigonometric.html#mpmath.radians), in the `mpmath` module.

```
sympy.cosd = lambda x : sympy.cos( sympy.mpmath.radians(x) )
```

Comment: Thanks, but it prints `cos(0.0174532925199433*x)`, which is not really readable either.

Comment: Huh. It works for me. For example, after defining `sympy.cosd` as above, I enter `sympy.cosd(60)` and it returns `0.5`. Maybe this is a version thing? I'm using `sympy 0.7.6`

Comment: `sympy.cosd(60)` also gives me `0.5`. I think it gives `cos(0.0174532925199433*x)` because the argument is a symbol : `x=sympy.Symbol('x')` I'm using it to do symbolic calculus (so I can check the formula), then I lambdify it for numerical application.

Comment: ah, I see now. not sure how to do that then.

Comment: I'll leave this answer here incase anyone stumbles over this question looking for a radian converter

Answer (score 0):

To keep the symbols in tact while using degrees, I did something like:

```
import sympy as sp
def tand(x):
    return sp.tan(x * sp.pi / 180)

def sind(x):
    return sp.sin(x * sp.pi / 180)

def cosd(x):
    return sp.cos(x * sp.pi / 180)
```

Example Results

```
In [5]: tand(60)
Out[5]: sqrt(3)
```