# how to fix floating point errors with trigonometric functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, precision, discord.py

I am making a discord bot with the discord.py library and I am currently working on the calculator function. Whilst trying to complete the sine, cosine and tan functions I have run into many floating-point errors. I have had a look around the internet but couldn't find anything understandable on this and would like to know how to fix it.

I understand that I could round the result to 1 D.P. However, I would like to have relatively precise numbers to a few decimal places (like 5). I have been trying to use the 'decimal' library to fix it though I've had no luck.

Running these commands on discord results in the responses:

'r-calc sine 30' --> '0.499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375'

'r-calc cosine 60' --> '0.50000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125'

I have the code:

```py
from decimal import Decimal as dec
@commands.command(name="calculator",
                      aliases=["calc"],
                      description="A multifunctional calculator for all your mathematical needs.",
                      brief="An extensive calculator",
                      usage="<Mode (+/-/*/etc.)> <Numbers to input>")
async def calculator(self, ctx, mode, *numbers: dec):
        Math.command_exec(ctx)
        mode = mode.lower()
        answer = dec(0)
        try:        
            ...
            if mode == "sine" or mode == "sin":
                answer = dec(math.sin(dec(numbers[0]) * dec(math.pi) / dec(180)))
            elif mode == "cos" or mode == "cosine":
                answer = dec(math.cos(dec(numbers[0]) * dec(math.pi) / dec(180)))
            elif mode == "tan" or mode == "tangent":
                answer = dec(math.tan(dec(numbers[0]) * dec(math.pi) / dec(180)))
        except Exception as ex:
            await ctx.send(f"Error: {str(ex)}")
        answer = dec(answer)
        await ctx.send(f"The answer:\n{str(answer)}")
```

Please help.

Comment: Why not use ```sin(dec(<your number>))```?

Comment: @Pencilcaseman Because math.sin(x) requires the angle in radians but for simplicity, I want the input to be in degrees. Therefore I must convert the input to radians

Comment: You're using the floating point sine and cosine functions, so the outputs are going to be floats, regardless of the inputs.  [You can look at the Decimal recipes for Decimal sine and cosine functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal-recipes), but keep in mind that sine and cosine mostly have irrational results, so you're still going to lose precision.

Comment: I've had a go with that and like you said I still don't get it accurate. I guess there isn't a way to make it accurate without rounding so I'll just do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The problem is not in the sin and cosine, but in the precision of ```math.py```. See my answer for more of an explaination

Comment: @Pencilcaseman the problem is not in the precision. Pi has infinite precision so you must use a symbolic math library, or a library with sind/cosd/tand that work on degrees. See [cosd and sind with sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31072815/995714)